# Upgrade to Airflow 1.10 - _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'task_instance.executor_config' in 'field list'")

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

I just updated to Airflow 1.10 following the instructions here: https://medium.com/datareply/apache-airflow-1-10-0-released-highlights-6bbe7a37a8e1

When I click on a DAG in the web GUI I get the following error:
`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'task_instance.executor_config' in 'field list'")`

Seemingly upgrading requires changes to the database. Is there a command to alter existing tables? I didn't find anything on this in the [Updating Airflow
docs](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#airflow-110).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, found out that there is a command `airflow upgradedb` that fixes this and should be run after upgrading from Airflow 1.9 to 1.10.

Answer (score 2):

`airflow upgradedb` won't work if you upgrade from airflow 1.8 directly to 1.10, you should upgrade to 1.9 first, use `airflow upgradedb` and then do the same process from 1.9 to 1.10.